# OHAttributedLabel Warning

Tags: iphone, xcode, uilabel

I am using OHAttributedLabel in my iPhone application but I am getting a warning.

```
Warning: the numberOfLines property is not yet supported by CoreText and OHAttributedLabel. (this property is ignored right now)
 This is a known issue (Help to solve this would be greatly appreciated).
 See https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel/issues/34
```

Also,I didn't got any solution for this can any one suggest me how to resolve it, If I upload my app without removing this warning will my app be rejected by apple.

Comment: IMO App will not be rejected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as the warning says, `numberOfLines` isn't supported by *OHAttributedLabel*. The only way to remove the warning is to just not set the `numberOfLines` property until *OHAttributedLabel* supports it.

If your app uses `NSLog()` it won't be rejected by Apple, but you should avoid it, because it's a bad habit. The log information will be useless to you and your users and it'll decrease performance if many log messages get sent.

Answer (score 0):

Due these error as it doesnot support most features of NSAtributedString.

It is better to use [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel/downloads).